# Displaying a simple checkbox in my play twirl template

Tags: html, scala, playframework

What does the HTML that renders my checkbox include all of this strange HTML?

```
<dl class=" " id="unSubscribe_field">
    <dt><label for="unSubscribe">unSubscribe</label></dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" name="unSubscribe" id="unSubscribe" >
    </dd>
    <dd class="info">format.boolean</dd>
</dl>
```

I just want to display a simple checkbox on the screen, I don't need all of this label and `dd` tags.

I am even using the custom way to render the tag:

```
@helper.input(form("unSubscribe")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="checkbox" name="@name" id="@id" >
}
```

My case class is:

```
case class SubscriptionManageForm(token: Option[String], unSubscribe: Boolean)
```

How can I display a simple input checkbox tag? Below is a screenshot of the current rending:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The template is using the default `FieldConstructor` because you don't specify your own `FieldConstructor` as an implicit value.

To write your own field constructor, start by writing a template named `myFieldConstructor.scala.html`, containing these lines:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
@elements.input
```

Then, in your view template, set an implicit value for your FieldConstructor inline:

```
@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructor.f) }

@helper.input(form("unSubscribe")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
                <input type="checkbox" name="@name" id="@id" >
            }
```

The template will use your custom field constructor to render the input text, as describe in your `myFieldConstructor.scala.html`.

More information here : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors

Answer (score 1):

"I just want to display a simple checkbox on the screen." If you don't want a use a template, you could create a simple checkbox like so.

```html
<label>
    Unsubscribe? <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="test1">
</label>

or iterating over server items...

@for(item <- model.getItems()) {
    <label>
 @item.labelText <input type="checkbox" name="@item.name" id="@item.id">
    </label>
}
```

My point is, you can keep is as simple as you want. If the Play templates are adding confusion, then keep it simple with basic HTML.